# Java. How to use "while" that program at the end asked : Do you want to search again?

Tags: java, search, while-loop, find, cpu-word

I want to ask you how to make It when proccess and do this again. I mean when program did his work It must to ask: Do you want search for other word, Yes or No? If Yes program will start again, if no exit.

I think about:

```
 int searchAgain = 0;
            System.out.println("Do you want search for other word?");
            System.out.println("1=Yes 2=No");
            searchAgain = input.nextInt();}
        else {
            System.out.println("Error...");
            }   
                if (searchAgain == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Write your word: ");
                    .....//I dont know what here

                }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Program closed.");
                    }
```

This is my current code:

```
    package lt.kvk.i3_2.kalasnikovas_stanislovas;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Miestai {


        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            String kitasStilius = "";
            while (!"Ne".equalsIgnoreCase(kitasStilius )) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Pasirinkite muzikos stiliu is saraso:");
            System.out.println();

            try {

                FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/Stiliai.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String stiliuSarasas;
                while((stiliuSarasas = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(stiliuSarasas);
                }
                fr.close();
                String stilius = input.nextLine();   
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/Miestai.txt"));
                int counter = 0;                
                String line;

                System.out.println("Ieskoma informacija apie " + stilius);
                ArrayList<String> miestuSarasas = new ArrayList<String>();
                String miestas = null;

                while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null){
                    if (line.trim().length() == 0) miestas = null;
                       else if (miestas == null) miestas = line;
                       int indexfound = line.indexOf(stilius);
                       if (indexfound > -1) {
                       counter++;
                       miestuSarasas.add(miestas);
                       }                   
                }
                if (counter > 0) {
                    System.out.println(stilius + " turi " + counter + " remejus: " + miestuSarasas);                    
                    System.out.println("Ar norite ieskoti informacijos apie kita stiliu?");
                    System.out.println("Iveskite: Taip arba Ne");
                    kitasStilius = input.next();

                    }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Klaida, nerastas muzikos stilius");
                    break;
                    }   
                        if ("Taip".equalsIgnoreCase(kitasStilius)) {
                        }
                        else if ("Ne".equalsIgnoreCase(kitasStilius)) {
                            System.out.println("Darbas baigtas.");

                        }
                            else{
                                System.out.println("Neteisingai pasirinkta.");
                                break;
                            }
                        bf.close();
                        }

            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error:" + e.toString());
            }
        }
        }
        private void searchWord(String textToSearch ){
            //your logic here which performs the search and prints the result
         }
     }
```

Program counting words (entered by keyboard) from file.txt and elect who repeated this word for ex.: if I enter word: `One` It shows:

```
Word One repeated 3 times by John, Elisa, Albert
```

file.txt looks like:

```
John //first line - name
One
Three
Four

Peter //first line - name
Two
Three

Elisa //first line - name
One
Three

Albert //first line - name
One
Three
Four

Nicole //first line - name
Two
Four
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code(slightly modified) in a `while` loop with condition on `searchAgain` as:

**EDIT:** Updating to accept the option as String:

```
 public class Testing {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select word from list:");
        System.out.println();

        String searchAgain = "";
        while(!"No".equalsIgnoreCase(searchAgain )){
           System.out.println("Do you want search for other word?");
           System.out.println("Enter: Yes or No");
           searchAgain = input.next();
           if ("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(searchAgain)) {
              System.out.println("Write your word: ");
              String textToSearch = input.next();
              searchWord(textToSearch );
           } else if ("No".equalsIgnoreCase(searchAgain)) {
                 System.out.println("Program closed.");
           } else{
                 System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
           }
        }
     }

     private void searchWord(String textToSearch ){
        //your logic here which performs the search and prints the result
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, how to call method, I never did that? use get.main() or how? :| sorry for stupid question

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: You should take a look at the Java Tutorial.  It will provide lots of examples that should help with these questions.  You might also take a Java Programming course.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas The above code goes in you main. As I put the comment `put your logic here/ or call the method to search the word`, you may embed your code at the place or make a rename your current main function with some cleaning to perform the search and call that method there. I will updated the answer with brief example of the second option as I prefer that one.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: I added the structure as I mentioned. Fill in the code as you want and your should be good.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: I notice, you haven't accepted answers to any of your questions. If you don't like them including this one one, it's fine, `otherwise you need to accept the answers` by clicking the arrow sign next to the vote count in front of the answer.

Comment: Thank you.
But I don't understand why this is needed: 'private void searchWord(String textToSearch ){
        //your logic here which performs the search and prints the result
     }'
This program working whitout It.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas **This is just to make your code clean  & modular**. If you don't want to create a method then put all your logic when I am calling `searchWord` method in the `main` method.

Comment: ANd maybe you can say how to make choice by Yes or No (string) but not by numbers (int). As you see System.out.println("1=Yes 2=No"); That because I dont know how to make.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: I updated the answer to accept `Yes or No` as String and ignored the case so that `YES and NO` also works.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are so genius :) You helped me so much.

Comment: When I use this: `searchWord(textToSearch );` gives me error: `textToSearch cannot be resolved to a variable.`

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: Update the question with your updated code. I will help you.

Comment: I updated my code, but as you see I wrote It in lithuanian language, if you can't understand what I wrote I can translate for you. I typed // comment marks `//  String textToSearch = input.next(); //   searchWord(textToSearch );` where I have problem. And I dont know really what I need to put searchWord method :|

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: I don't understand the language but let me try correcting your program itself. Wait for 5 minutes.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: I updated the answer with both ways, which I think working. Please copy both the version from the answer as I would like to remove them from the answer. Let me know once done.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: Let me know once done and also don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I copied, thank you very much. This `Version 2 with separate method:` very well. Now code looks perfect.
In my task left only if possible use any constructors(not empty)? And do you know how to sort(order) answers by abc? When I receive for ex.: `Word One repeated 3 times by John, Elisa, Albert` these 3 words order by abc `...Albert, Elisa, John` If you dont have free time anymore I'll understand, I'm very thankful for you for that what you did for me.
Ok, I accepted.